# Import error happens while using script, but good in interpreter

Tags: python, import, interpreter

I'm running my python scripts using the `python 3 A/file.py` command in the terminal, and my file structure is the following:

```
--A
----file.py
----B
--------SomeClass.py
```

The error is from the import line inside `file.py`: `from A.B.SomeClass import SomeClass`
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named A`
But it works well when I'm using PyCharm interactive running button, how could I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

I’ve tried shebang and all my python modules have an `__init__.py` file.

Comment: `init.py` or `__init__.py`? The latter is right not the first.

Comment: Directory `A` is a root for absolute imports because the main script is in it (the current working directory doesn't matter). Therefore: `from B.SomeClass import SomeClass`.